# Changing cookie expiration with Laravel 4

Tags: cookies, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to change the expiration time of the remember me cookie when the user checks the option and logs in, but the expiration time doesn't change when I run this code. What do I need to do to fix this in Laravel 4?

More specifically what I want to do is set the expiration time to 12 hours. I tried the App:after method but every time that code runs, it refreshes the existing cookie back to the original 12 hours. How would I make it run so that it doesn't do that?

LoginController.php

```
class LoginController extends BaseController {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
}

public function getIndex()
{   
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::action('HomeController@usersIndex')
            ->with('message', 'You are already logged in.');
    }

    return View::make('guests.login');
}

public function postIndex()
{
    $validation = User::validateForm(Input::all());

    if ($validation->passes()) {
        $user = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        // Try to log the user in.
        if (Auth::attempt($user, Input::has('remember_me'))) {  
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }

        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors(array('password' => 'The username or password you entered is incorrect.'))
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }

    return Redirect::to('login')
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
}

}
```

filters.php

```
App::after(function($request, $response) {
    if ( Auth::check()){
        $ckname=Auth::getRecallerName(); //Get the name of the cookie, where remember me expiration time is stored
        $ckval=Cookie::get($ckname); //Get the value of the cookie
        return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make($ckname,$ckval,720)); //change the expiration time
    }
});
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@usersIndex');
Route::get('logout', 'HomeController@logout');

Route::controller('login', 'LoginController');
Route::controller('register', 'RegistrationController');
Route::controller('password', 'PasswordController');
```

Comment: you can't change it in your controller, you have to change it in `App::after` method

Comment: @Trying Tobemyself What I want to do is set the expiration time to 12 hours. I tried the App:after method but every time that code runs, it tacks/adds on another 12 hours to the existing cookie. How would I make it run so that it doesn't do that?

Comment: Its working for me, can you post the code

Comment: @Trying Tobemyself I've edited my post with the existing code I've used that includes the App:after method.

Comment: Are you sure it adds 12hours instead of overwriting the time?because the exact same code works for me. can you post the cookie details?

Comment: @Trying Tobemyself I apologize. It doesn't add 12 hours. It overwrites/refreshes back to the original 12 hours. How would I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35236/discussion-between-trying-tobemyself-and-user1307016)

Comment: @Trying Tobemyself I apologize about the lateness. I wasn't expecting a discussion in a chat room.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `App::after` method to change rememberme cookie expiration time.
so in your `filters.php` file `find App::after()` method and change the cookie expiration time. For example-

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
  if ( Auth::check()){
      $ckname=Auth::getRecallerName(); //Get the name of the cookie, where remember me expiration time is stored
      $ckval=Cookie::get($ckname); //Get the value of the cookie
      return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make($ckname,$ckval,360)); //change the expiration time
  }
});
```

From Discussion:

You: @Trying What I want to do is set the expiration time to 12 hours. I tried the `App:after` method but every time that code runs, It overwrites/refreshes back to the original 12 hours. How would I fix this?

Me: You can try setting session value in ur login method and thn check it in `App::after` method, the session value,
If it exists update the cookie and delete the session value,
If u do this it will only update the cookie once i,e when u login.

Example:-

```
Login code
if (Auth::attempt($user, Input::has('remember_me'))) {  
   Session::put('key',value);   
   return Redirect::to('/');
}

App after method
App::after(function($request, $response) {
    if(Session::has('key')){
    if ( Auth::check()){
        $ckname=Auth::getRecallerName(); //Get the name of the cookie, where remember me expiration time is stored
        $ckval=Cookie::get($ckname); //Get the value of the cookie
        Session::forget('key');
        return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make($ckname,$ckval,720)); //change the expiration time
    }
}
});
```